# not getting a decimal to print

Tags: java, decimal

So I am trying to find the rate of attendance in a class.. using attend=total present / tot students.. for some reason I keep getting Zero for the answer. I have the attend variable initialized as a double. Before anyone answers I always like to be clear that this is homework. Im having a heck of a time because I cant seem to use a compiler to debug like I normally would for C++, so if anyone has any recommendation on a IDE that would allow that I would greatly appreciate that help as well. My code is below

```
 tot_stu+=students;
 tot_pres+=present;
 absent = tot_stu - tot_pres;
 attend = tot_pres / tot_stu;

 //test

 System.out.println(tot_stu);
 System.out.println(tot_pres);
 System.out.println(attend);

 //output
 System.out.println("The school has " +tot_stu+ " students");
 System.out.println("The school has " +tot_pres+ " students present");
 System.out.println("The school has "+absent+" students absent");
 System.out.println("The schools over all attendence rate is: " + attend);
 System.out.println("");
```

I keep getting this output

```
 Please enter the total number of classes: 2
 Enter the total students in class 1:10
  Enter how many students were present in class 1: 5
 10
 5
 0.0
 The school has 10 students
 The school has 5 students present
 The school has 5 students absent
 The schools over all attendance rate is: 0.0

 Enter the total students in class 2: 65
 Enter how many students were present in class 2: 7
 65
 7
 0.0
 The school has 65 students
 The school has 7 students present
 The school has 58 students absent
 The schools over all attendance rate is: 0.0
```

> 

Comment: Do you use `double` or `int` for your variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you probably use `int` for `tot_pres` and `tot_stu`. To fix, change your line to this:

```
 attend = tot_pres / (tot_stu+0.0);
```

or

```
 attend = tot_pres / ((double)tot_stu);
```

or any other variation! The only one that spits out the `int` value for the result is when both denominator and numerator are both `int`.

When you do this, compiler reads the denominator as a `double` instead of an `int`.

Comment: Thank you, can you please help me understand why this worked?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that either tot_pres or tot_stu is double.
or you can simply do the following..
((double)tot_pres)/tot_stu;

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're using a floating point type and not an int.
attend has to be a floating point type
if tot_pres and tot_stu are int, cast them to float when dividing like this:

```
attend = (double)tot_pres /tot_stu;
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you replace the part of the code with this ?

```
double attend;
int total_students = 2;
int total_present = 10;
attend = total_present/total_students;
```

Comment: well, my code in its entirety will not allow more students present than there are total students, but when I comment out that line of code I get a positive 5.0 for attend

Comment: Well, the reason for getting zero value is then uninitialized variable. tried to run your code and game 5.0 already. Not quite sure why the casting worked.